# Add methods to class dynamically when they are called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a script that does something like:

```
class Foo():
   def magic_method(...):
       return called_function

a = Foo()

a.bar()
> bar
a.foo()
> foo
```

So basically, if the method doesn't exist in Foo(), don't return an error, but accept it and use it as a string to do other stuff.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: You could include a `__getattr__` method in your class to then return a function that returns its name.

Comment: What's the point? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to make this: https://github.com/Basdbruijne/UniversalWrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `__getattr__` magic method:

```
class Foo():
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda: name
```

Now:

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.something()
'something'
```

You need to return `lambda` so calling `.something()` returns the name of the method (and not just `.something`).